# Можно ли говорить "подавляющее количество"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли говорить "подавляющее количество"?
Слышал много раз "подавляющее большинство".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, словосочетание «подавляющее большинство» встречается гораздо  чаще, чем «подавляющее количество» (по числу вхождений в корпус русского языка, - почти в шестьдесят раз). Но будет неправильно думать, что эти словосочетания полностью эквивалентны, а второе является просто неказистым вариантом первого.
В нац.корпусе есть примеры употребления  «подавляющего количества», в которых замена «количества» «большинством» вряд ли будет уместной.

На нищий, темный и эксплуатируемый народ падает подавляющее количество потреблявшейся ранее у нас водки и «сивухи». [Н. Тяпугин. Народные заблуждения и научная правда об алкоголе (1926)]

Подавляющее количество кредитных договоров заключено с работниками сельского хозяйства, из которых 80 процентов рядовые труженики. [Евгений Савченко. Человек и труд // «Наш современник», 2002.06.15]

Comment: Да, "подавляющее большинство" подразумевает, что есть ещё и какое-никакое меньшинство, а "подавляющее количество" — это просто "дофига" :)